# best way in linux to get usb device added notifications in c

Tags: c, linux, usb

what Linux library should i use to get asynchronous notifications of added usb devices? I'd like my program to work on any Linux device so I'll need to use a library that isn't specific to one Linux version

Comment: You could [write a udev rule](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) to call your program.

Comment: but my program will need to always be running like a daemon in the background if there's a way to create a udev rule to send a signal to my program then maybe that would work

Comment: Check out http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/libudev/, tutorial here http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/

Comment: Did any of the answers help you out?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using 'C' then I would suggest using the notification features of libudev. Here is a good link with example 'C' code.

[libudev Document](http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/)

Hope that helps.

--Jim

Answer (score 1):

You need to include what language you are using before we can talk libraries, but if you want to just hook into a shell and parse infos you can use [udevadm](http://linux.die.net/man/8/udevadm). You also will have to consider user mode, versus kernel mode, and you will most likely have to run your program or in kernel mode to be able to listen for this type of event.

Comment: in the title of my question i mentioned using C

Comment: @rjs I would look into using http://www.libusb.org/ then. That would be a good start. A lot of comercial grade applications use it, and it's open source.