# C++, BBB, Debian: How to know when an USB drive is mounted/inserted

Tags: c++, debian, beagleboneblack, usb-drive

### Description:

I'm developing a "kiosk" app on a BeagleBone black (using wxWidgets, but this question/answer may or may not be wxWidgets-related) and i need to know when a USB drive is inserted (and mounted?).

What i'd like the most is to catch a "system event" that tells my app that the drive (or thumbdrive) is present so i can do some automation on it, but i'd be fine also to check for the drive in a specific instant (when the user enter in the relevant UI page).

The BBB detects when the USB is plugged in, but did'nt mount it (unless i open the FileManager, then i can see the drive folder in */media/debian/drivename*) so i can't just check that path from my app.

I've read a lot of questions about this here, but none of them seems right to me (or perhaps i'm too inexperienced); as example, there's not a */dev/ttyUSB* file, or i don't know how to use the links in */dev/disk/by-id*.

### My question:

how can i know when a USB drive is plugged in the BBB? And when i have this info, how do i mount it (if needed?)

### Some notes:

- I have no problem on taking advantage of the fact that the BBB have just one USB port, if a generic solution is more complicated
- I'll accept either generic or wxWidgets-specific solution

Thanks

### EDIT:

following @markus-nm comment and that link, i ended up with this working rule:

```
ACTION=="add",      KERNEL=="sd[a-z]*", RUN+="/usr/bin/pmount --sync --umask 000 --noatime %k"
ACTION=="remove",   KERNEL=="sd[a-z]*", RUN+="/usr/bin/pumount %k"
```

It works (i have a "sda1" folder in /media/) but it is not perfect:
if the system is shut-off while the USB drive is in, then the drive removed, then 
powered on, there's still the "sda1" folder.
My undersdanding is that the "remove event" never occured and so that folder is still there.

What should i do?

Comment: Most file managers / desktops have an "automount" option, that would be an easy answer if yours has one to enable, then monitoring the mountpoint folder for changes (new directories) should work, as long as they're not recycled for new devices

Comment: Have you tried to use udev? See this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891535/best-way-in-linux-to-get-usb-device-added-notifications-in-c

Comment: @markus-nm : followed that link, i ended up with a rule file: question edited 'cause still not "perfect"